# Delay dropdown mouseleft 2 second

Tags: css

Could you please help me? I'm trying to delay 2 seconds my dropdown after user leaving mouse, I tried insert several transition in every CSS selector for many hours but without any success.

```css
/* Navbar container */
.navbar {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
  font-family: Arial;
}

/* Links inside the navbar */
.navbar a {
  float: left;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

/* The dropdown container */
.dropdown {
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
}

/* Dropdown button */
.dropdown .dropbtn {
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  background-color: inherit;
  font: inherit; /* Important for vertical align on mobile phones */
  margin: 0; /* Important for vertical align on mobile phones */
}
```

```html
<div class="navbar">
  <a href="#home">Home</a>
  <a href="#news">News</a>
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="dropbtn">Dropdown
      <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
    </button>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <div class="header">
        <h2>Mega Menu</h2>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="column">
          <h3>Category 1</h3>
          <a href="#">Link 1</a>
          <a href="#">Link 2</a>
          <a href="#">Link 3</a>
        </div>
        <div class="column">
          <h3>Category 2</h3>
          <a href="#">Link 1</a>
          <a href="#">Link 2</a>
          <a href="#">Link 3</a>
        </div>
        <div class="column">
          <h3>Category 3</h3>
          <a href="#">Link 1</a>
          <a href="#">Link 2</a>
          <a href="#">Link 3</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I tried to insert `transition-delay: 0s;` and `transition-duration: 2s;` on `.navbar a:hover, .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {` but didnt work.

I want something like this => http://jsfiddle.net/odsb86o2/1/
Test my code here => https://jsfiddle.net/foks8bt5/

Could you please help me?

Comment: Your problem is that CSS transitions don't work along with `display: none;` turning into `display: block`. A transition will only do something like fade in an opacity, where the values are quantitative. The `display` property, by contrast, only has discreet values, i.e. there's nothing to transition.

Comment: Was typing out exactly what Nicolas said, but yea he is correct. However there are tricks that can be done accordingly with or without javascript depending on whether the content is allowed to remain in the DOM or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### TL;DR. `display` cannot be animated. Use `opacity` instead.

As the others mentioned in the comments, you cannot animate between `display: none;` and `display: block;`. In this scenario, a typical CSS solution is to use `opacity` instead.

Please see the slightly tweaked code sample below. The only critical changes are replacing `display: none;`/`display: block;` with `opacity:0;`/`opacity:1;`.

Note I've also added `pointer-events: none;` to invisible state and put `pointer-events: all;` back when it's visible. This is to avoid the invisible mega menu blocking any elements below it while it's inactive.

```css
/* Navbar container */
.navbar {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
  font-family: Arial;
}

/* Links inside the navbar */
.navbar a {
  float: left;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

/* The dropdown container */
.dropdown {
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
}

/* Dropdown button */
.dropdown .dropbtn {
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  background-color: inherit;
  font: inherit; /* Important for vertical align on mobile phones */
  margin: 0; /* Important for vertical align on mobile phones */
  cursor: pointer;
}

/* Add a red background color to navbar links on hover */
.navbar a:hover, .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  background-color: red;
}

/* Dropdown content (hidden by default) */
.dropdown-content {
  opacity: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
  transition: opacity .5s;
  transition-delay: .5s;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

/* Mega Menu header, if needed */
.dropdown-content .header {
  background: red;
  padding: 16px;
  color: white;
}

/* Show the dropdown menu on hover */
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  opacity: 1;
  pointer-events: all;
}

/* Create three equal columns that floats next to each other */
.column {
  float: left;
  width: 33.33%;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #ccc;
  height: 250px;
}

/* Style links inside the columns */
.column a {
  float: none;
  color: black;
  padding: 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
}

/* Add a background color on hover */
.column a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

/* Clear floats after the columns */
.row:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<div class="navbar">
  <a href="#home">Home</a>
  <a href="#news">News</a>
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="dropbtn">Dropdown
      <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
    </button>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <div class="header">
        <h2>Mega Menu</h2>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="column">
          <h3>Category 1</h3>
          <a href="#">Link 1</a>
          <a href="#">Link 2</a>
          <a href="#">Link 3</a>
        </div>
        <div class="column">
          <h3>Category 2</h3>
          <a href="#">Link 1</a>
          <a href="#">Link 2</a>
          <a href="#">Link 3</a>
        </div>
        <div class="column">
          <h3>Category 3</h3>
          <a href="#">Link 1</a>
          <a href="#">Link 2</a>
          <a href="#">Link 3</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```